# How can i get the total occurrence of letter K?

Tags: c#, console

I want to check on how many times does k appears. this is
what i have done so far and am not getting the results.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int count = 0;
        string str = "hnfdjkkedjjykukyukrtrnrkkkkt";
        string l;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            l = str.Substring(1, 1);
            if (l == "k")
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("k appears " + count++ + " times");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `l = str.Substring(i, 1);` and it should work

Comment: this works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try :

```
int count = str.Count(c => c=='k')
```

Hope this help :-)

Comment: Note: to use this code you have to include `System.Linq` namespace

Comment: Indeed thanks for the add :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can go as simple as

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s = "aasfkkfasfas";
        int count = s.Count(l => l== 'k');

        Console.WriteLine(count);
    }
}
```

Calling Substring for each letter is really not the best solution. Keep in mind that string implements IEnumerable so you can also do it like this:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string s = "aasfkkfasfas";
        int count = 0;
        foreach(char c in s)
        {
            if(c == 'k') 
                count++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(count);
    }
}
```

This is closer to your original solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `RegEx` (Regular Expressions) for that but it's kind of overkill for your use case.

It's found in the namespace `System.Text.RegularExpressions` (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)).

```
Regex.Matches(text, pattern).Count
```

In your case, it would be

```
Regex.Matches("hnfdjkkedjjykukyukrtrnrkkkkt", "[k]").Count
```